# AspNetCore Options pattern with constructor dependency

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an option class which like the following

```
public class EmailOptions
{
    public EmailOptions(IEmailConfiguration account) {
        this.Configuration = account;
    }
    public string DefaultFromAddress { get; set; }
    public string DefaultFromDisplayName { get; set; }
    public IEmailConfiguration Configuration { get; }
}
```

The IEmailConfiguration interface is there because in some cases I can have an Smtp library and so I need an Smtp based configuration while in some other cases I can use other services which needs a different configuration. Example:

```
public class ApiKeyConfiguration : IEmailConfiguration
{
    public ApiKeyConfiguration() {
    }
    public string AccountName { get; set; }
    public string AccountKey { get; set; }
}
```

or

```
public class SmtpConfiguration : IEmailConfiguration
{
    public SmtpConfiguration() {
    }
    public string Host { get; set; }
    public string Port { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Domain { get; set; }
    public bool EnableSsl { get; set; }
    public bool UseDefaultCredentials { get; set; }
}
```

I am sure I am registering the correct implementation with

```
services.AddTransient<IEmailConfiguration, ApiKeyConfiguration>();
```

However when I try to inject an IOption<> into a controller I am getting the following error:

> [13:56:26 ERR] An unhandled exception has occurred: Cannot create instance of type 'EmailOptions' because it is missing a public parameterless constructor. 
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot create instance of type 'EmailOptions' because it is missing a public parameterless constructor.
>   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBinder.CreateInstance(Type type)

Of course I can add a parameterless constructor to the class but how do I ensure that the DI container will create an instance of my class by using the constructor with parameter dependency?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, you may try to create own implementation of [IConfigureOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.options.iconfigureoptions-1?view=aspnetcore-2.0).

> Represents something that configures the TOptions type. Note: These are run before all IPostConfigureOptions.

So do something like this:

```
public class ConfigureEmailOptions : IConfigureOptions<EmailOptions>
{
    private readonly IEmailConfiguration _account;
    public ConfigureMyOptions(IEmailConfiguration account)
    {
        _account = account;
    }

    public void Configure(EmailOptions options)
    {
        options.Configuration = _account;
        ...
    }
}
```

and register it as

```
services.AddTransient<IConfigureOptions<EmailOptions>, ConfigureEmailOptions>();
```

and your option class should be just

```
public class EmailOptions
{
    public string DefaultFromAddress { get; set; }
    public string DefaultFromDisplayName { get; set; }
    public IEmailConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's saying you need a public parameterless constructor.

Add

```
public EmailOptions() {

}
```

Comment: :D well this was absolutely clear. Do I am ensured that however the options will be created by using the constructor with the parameter? I know that usually DI containers uses always the constructor with most parameters but this is exactly what is mandatory in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the way configuration works in ASP.NET Core, it will always use a parameterless constructor. Although it's not the only reason why, one particularly good reason is that the configuration setup happens *before* any DI services are registered, meaning it couldn't inject anything if it wanted to.

Long and short, there's no way to satisfy something like `IEmailConfiguration` in a strongly-typed configuration class. It's frankly a bad idea anyways. Just let your configuration class be a simple entity and inject *that* into a service or something that handles your email stuff, instead of the other way around.